# VBA Event Handler To Return Value

Tags: vba, function, event-handling, bloomberg

I have an event handler Sub that listens for a response message from the Bloomberg API, and stores it in a Dd array.

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-call-an-event-handler), **event handlers must be subs**, but I would like to do further analysis on the data in my main method.

How can I reference the array created in the event handler, such that I can continue to process the data?

Event handler:

```
Private Sub session_ProcessEvent(ByVal obj As Object)

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim eventObj As blpapicomLib2.Event
    Set eventObj = obj

    If Application.Ready Then
        If eventObj.EventType = PARTIAL_RESPONSE Or eventObj.EventType = RESPONSE Then
            Dim it As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
            Set it = eventObj.CreateMessageIterator()
            Dim numResponse As Integer
            numResponse = 0
            Dim data() As Variant
            Do While it.Next()
                numResponse = numResponse + 1
                Dim msg As Message
                Set msg = it.Message
                Dim securityData As Element
                Dim securityName As Element
                Dim fieldData As Element
                Set securityData = msg.GetElement("securityData")
                Set securityName = securityData.GetElement("security")
                Set fieldData = securityData.GetElement("fieldData")
                Sheet1.Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = securityName.Value
                Dim numDates As Integer
                Dim numFields As Integer
                numDates = fieldData.NumValues
                numFields = fieldData.GetValue(0).NumElements
                ReDim data(numDates, numFields, numResponse)
                Dim b As Integer
                For b = 0 To numDates - 1
                    Dim fields As blpapicomLib2.Element
                    Set fields = fieldData.GetValue(b)
                    Dim a As Integer

                    For a = 0 To numFields - 1
                        Dim field As Element
                        Set field = fields.GetElement(a)
                        data(b, a, numResponse) = field.Value
                        Sheet1.Cells(currentRow, a + 5).Value = data(b, a, numResponse)
                    Next
                    currentRow = currentRow + 1
                Next b
            Loop

        '     skip a row for next security
            currentRow = currentRow + 1

        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

...and the sub I would like to process the array in here...

```
Public Sub RefDataExample()

    ' Calculate the number of securities and fields
    Dim numSecurity As Integer
    Dim numFields As Integer

    numSecurity = 0
    numFields = 0

    ' clear data area
    Range("D4", "H60000").Clear

    Do While Cells(numSecurity + 4, 1).Value <> ""
        numSecurity = numSecurity + 1
    Loop

    Do While Cells(numFields + 4, 2).Value <> ""
        numFields = numFields + 1
    Loop

    Dim sSecurity() As String
    Dim sFields() As Variant

    ReDim sSecurity(0 To numSecurity - 1) As String
    ReDim sFields(0 To numFields - 1) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To numSecurity - 1
        sSecurity(i) = Cells(i + 4, 1).Value
    Next i

    For i = 0 To numFields - 1
        sFields(i) = Cells(i + 4, 2).Value
    Next i

    bbControl.MakeRequest sSecurity, sFields

    'Process response array here

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome!  Please see "[mcve]" and also "[ask]".

Comment: Hi--happy to edit my question, could you clarify which of those standards this doesn't meet? The query isn't truly dependent on the example, as the conceptual question of "can an event handler return a value" is at its core. That said, the example is complete, though I suppose it could be shrunk, and is verifiable.

Comment: maybe he was referring to the fact that subs do not return values, in that case, this is not a question at all. on the other hand, why not use a public variable to store the array, so that you can access it from both subs

Comment: How would you go about making the variable public? For instance, I change the name of the event handler from 

'Public Sub session_ProcessEvent(ByVal obj As Object)' and then made a test 'processData()' sub which references a variable from the event handler, and it is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
Dim data() As Variant
```

from within all the subs it currently appears in (like from within your `session_ProcessEvent()`)

and place

```
Public data As Variant
```

at the top of the module containing your sub (actually you can place it at the top of any module you like)

and you'll have ”data” visible from all subs/functions of your project

Comment: So I've tried that, but if data is an array, I get an error telling me that arrays can't be public variables.

Comment: who's telling you that? In VBA that's perfectly legal! Double check all you project and ensure: 1) there's no _"dimming"_ of any `data()` variable inside any sub/function (while leaving any _"ReDimmin"_ in place) 2) place `Public data() As Variant` at the very top of any (i.e. whatever, but only one!) module